# How to check with google/apiclient if a directory with a specified id exists in Google Drive?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I tried:

```
count($drive->files->listFiles([
    'q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and id='$driveDirId'"
])['files']) > 0
```

but Drive query language [doesn't seem to have an `id` term](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms#file_properties)

I would only need checking for directories I have access to, of course.

Comment: Hi, you can also use [Files:get ](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%22252%22%7D#try-it) to retrieve particular item and then check for [metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)  in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing this:

```
$driveFile = $drive->files->get($driveDirId, [
    'supportsAllDrives' => true,
]);
if ($driveFile === null) {
    return false;
}
if ($driveFile->getMimeType() === 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder') {
    return true;
} else {
    throw new Error("$driveDirId is not a directory");
}
```